# Not able to set CALayer background image in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I am not able to set the background image of CALayer. I have tried every possible way.
This is how i am trying to set background image.

```
-(void)addPlane{

CGSize planeSize = CGSizeMake(350, 200);


CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];

layer.frame = CGRectMake(480/2 - planeSize.width/2, 320/2 - planeSize.height/2 -20, planeSize.width, planeSize.height);
layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);


layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.3]CGColor];
layer.cornerRadius = 10;
layer.borderWidth = 4;
layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"card9.png"].CGImage;
[transformLayer addSublayer:layer];}
```

I have used this line of code also to set the background image of CALayer.

```
    [layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"card9.png"]] CGColor]];
```

Comment: Where do you add this `transformLayer` to your mainView(layer)?

Comment: yes to the main view in viewdidload

Comment: Try to set the background to a solid color to see if it's an image loading problem.

Comment: show that code too. transformLayer is a property of yourVC? Am I right?

Comment: i am able to add solid color..

Comment: @ankyy: Instead of image, you can add solid color? Double check with that, If yes, you must check with your images whether added or not. Otherwise check with image name..